# vis.js timeline add buttons to show day week or month

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Im trying to create a "booking" system with vis.js as I like the horizontal zoom layout and the ability to add items that need to get booked. I need to add buttons that on click will display the current day or the week or the month view on the timeline.

```
    <div id=""visualization></div>
    <ul class="btn-cluster">
     <li class="btn-cluster__item btn"><a class="btn-cluster__link--day">day</a></li>
    <li class="btn-cluster__item btn"><a class="btn-cluster__link--day">week</a></li>
<li class="btn-cluster__item btn"><a class="btn-cluster__link--day">month</a></li>
    </ul>




var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var groups    = {};
var items     = new vis.DataSet([
  {
    id: 'item1',
    content: 'item content'
  },

]) ;
var options   = {};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
```

Comment: Are you asking what the timeline API call is for setting the view to a user specified range? Or ask you asking for how to calculate what the range should be for current day/week/month?

Comment: Its no a specific range as such i would think,  it is to set the view either by the current day, or current week or current month. hope it makes sense

Comment: A day is a range though. Which is to say it has a start timestamp and an end timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the view on the timeline to a user specified range such as a day, week or month, you can use

```
timeline.setWindow(start, end [, options])
```

For example if you want to set the timeline to focus on today with a view width of 24hours you could do the following.

```
var ONE_DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var now = new Date();
var nowInMs = now.getTime();
var oneDayFromNow = nowInMs + ONE_DAY_IN_MS;
timeline.setWindow(nowInMs, oneDayFromNow);
```

Comment: Thanks @bhspencer it got me to the hour view but set it a day from the time now to the same time tomorrow. would be preferred if it was just the current day i'm in. And week?

Comment: Ah that's what I was looking for since many hours. Infact when I realized that setting the width of the day is not configurable and what needed is to set the focus area of interest, it makes sense now. 

==Some useful examples==
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/styling/dayScaleWithCalendarWeek.html
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/functionLabelFormats.html

When it says miliseconds ago, seconds ago, month ago, year ago and light year ago ha ha!!